# Laravel: Change base URL?

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

When I use `secure_url()` or `asset()`, it links to my site's domain ***without*** "www", i.e. "example.com".

How can I change it to link to "www.example.com"?

Comment: Any specific reason for changing it to www.example.com ?

Comment: I simply prefer it to have "www". I also do all my marketing using "www" and I'd rather keep using it cross site.

Comment: I've never implemented this, but I just had a play around with it now. If you update the `url` in `config/app.php` to `www.example.com` then when you generate URLs using URL helpers it appears to generate URLs with the `www` prefix. Give it a go and let me know how you get on.

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28496416/laravel-configurate-force-https/28498687#28498687) explains how to create a service provider that forces some changes to the URL generator (which is what the `secure_url` and `asset` helper functions use internally). You can use that code but replace the line `$generator->forceSchema('https');` in the provider `boot` method, with `$generator->forceRootUrl(Request::getScheme() . '://www.yourdomain.com');`. And now your URL should be generated like you want.

Answer (score 80):

First change your application URL in the file **config/app.php** (or the APP_URL value of your **.env** file):

```
'url' => 'http://www.example.com',
```

Then, make the URL generator use it. Add thoses lines of code to the file **app/Providers/AppServiceProvider.php** in the **boot** method:

```
\URL::forceRootUrl(\Config::get('app.url'));    
// And this if you wanna handle https URL scheme
// It's not usefull for http://www.example.com, it's just to make it more independant from the constant value
if (\Str::contains(\Config::get('app.url'), 'https://')) {
    \URL::forceScheme('https');
    //use \URL:forceSchema('https') if you use laravel < 5.4
}
```

That's all folks.

Comment: Laravel uses HTTP_HOST from the request's payload to generate urls. That is a solution to change that.

Comment: Note that it's URL::forceScheme not forceSchem**a**

Comment: @A.J.Brown yes true, for laravel >= 5.4 the change is there: https://github.com/laravel/framework/commit/39e8c83af778d8086b0b5e8f4f2e21331b015b39, i've updated the answer thx

Comment: this works in Laravel 7.22.2 , nice thanks ( I need to redirect some folder to another server in apache and works!)

Comment: I need to add a:  use Illuminate\Support\Facades\URL; on top of file and set config route like:   \Illuminate\Support\Facades\Config

Comment: this is not working in laravel 9 for request object

Comment: @BhavinThummar hi, what do you mean by "for request object" ? I'll try with Laravel 9 later.

Comment: Class 'Str' not found in Laravel 5.6.40

Comment: @SanjayGoswami you can use str_contains instead of \Str::contains if Laravel < 5.8

Answer (score 2):

`.env` file change in

```
APP_URL='http://www.example.com'
```

**config/app.php :**

```
'url' => env('APP_URL', 'http://www.example.com')
```

In controller or View call with config method

```
$url = config('app.url');
print_r($url);
```