# Using absolute paths in Laravel with wamp

Tags: php, laravel, wamp, absolute-path

I'm developing a Laravel project using wamp stack on windows. My project is located in a separate folder like ***C:\wamp64\www\[project name]***. The annoying problem is with url paths in code. I want to handle them in a way that they work both locally and on production environment. 
For example this an absolute link:

```
<a href="/posts/tags/{{ $tag  }}">
```

It is intended to navigate user to ***[project name]/posts/...*** . In other words I want to get project root with a slash. If this is not possible, what is the correct way of handling paths then (on development and production environment). I'm a little confused with this. Please provide detailed information considering both WAMP and Laravel. And please give information about relative paths, too.

Comment: you want to redirect to route url ?

Comment: @iCoders I want to set an href starting from project root (absolute path) whenever required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So what I finally did was to use the suggested method by @iCoders plus having APP_URL set in **.env** file to ***http://localhost/[project_name]/public***. 
This way url method resolves the correct path provided that your **config/app.php** contains **'url' => env('APP_URL', 'http://localhost')** and you make the URL generator use APP_URL. For more information, check this link:
[Laravel: Change base URL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35304448/laravel-change-base-url)
To differentiate development and production environments different .env files can be used for each.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `url` method url method will return base url

```
<a href="{{url('/posts/tags/'.$tag)}}">edit tag</a>
```

**url()**

The url function generates a fully qualified URL to the given path

Comment: This takes me to "http://localhost/posts/tags/..." instead of "http://localhost/[project name]/posts/tags/..."

Comment: are you using blade tempalte ?

Comment: Yes, I use blade.

Comment: then it might be cache .clear cache of lartavel and browser.thsi will work definately

Comment: Do you mean by running 'php artisan cache:clear' from CLI? I did this, but it had not any effect. Also I cleared chrome's cache data.

Comment: i dont why like this for you .till now i used this method in may project it works fine for me..just try from other browser