# Change the base URL programatically in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5, routes

I am using Laravel 5.5

Currently `URL::to('/');` outputs `http://www.example.com`

I want `URL::to('/');` to output `http://www.example.com/something`

Could you please tell me how to implement this ?

Comment: have you tried `URL::to('something')`?

Comment: follow this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35304448/laravel-change-base-url

Comment: Can you even call `URL::to();` without parameter?

Comment: @kerbholz I have updated my question

Comment: @Wreigh I need to get the output by `URL::to('/');` only.

Answer (score 6):

First change your application URL in the file `config/app.php` (or the APP_URL value of your .env file):

```
'url' => env('APP_URL', 'http://localhost')
```

Then, add thoses lines of code to the file `app/Providers/AppServiceProvider.php` in the boot method:

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Register any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Bootstrap any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        \URL::forceRootUrl(config('app.url'));        
    }
}
```

Comment: Please take a moment to read through the [editing help](//stackoverflow.com/editing-help) in the [help]. Formatting on Stack Overflow is different than other sites.

Comment: Man, the format is really bad, haha, BUT you saved my life <3

Answer (score 1):

In the `config/app.php` file you can set the base url.

```
'url' => 'http://www.example.com/something'
```

Set it using the `config` helper to change it programatically.

`config(['url' => 'http://www.example.com/something'])`

Comment: I tried your code but when I echo `URL::to('/');` it still shows http://www.example.com

Comment: I think you need to declare `app` index key before `url`. It's work on laravel tinker : `config(['app' => ['url' => 'https://google.com']])`