# My Laravel App Links in CentOS 7 show ip address instead of domain name

Tags: centos7, laravel-5.6

I am developing a Laravel 5.6 app and have hosted it in localhost. 
I have deployed it in CentOS 7 on an Apache web server to test how it behaves.
I'm loading the js and css files using {{ asset('js/app.js') }} format. For example . 
This doesn't load the files but when I remove asset() and load it like , it works.

The problem is that when I use {{ route('password.request') }} for links, it shows the ip 10.0.9.15/password/reset instead of the domain name like https://chandi.bushlot.ca/password/reset

It works very well in my local machine. I encountered this issue when I deployed it in CentOS. I have done a lot of research but I'm not getting anywhere with this.

The link to the project is https://chandi.bushlot.ca/

Comment: Check your `.env` file for the `APP_URL` value and check your `config/app.php` for the `url` value. Perhaps you are missing one or have that IP address in there for some reason.

Comment: Thanks for this. I checked the APP_URL in .env file and also the config/app.php. the URL was http://localhost. I even changed it to https://chandi.bushlot.ca but I still have the same issue.

Comment: I finally found the solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35304448/laravel-change-base-url