# laravel invalid route action with subdomain

Tags: php, laravel

What is the proper way to add a subdomain into your routes?  I have a laravel/homestead project working on my local computer but when I move it to HostGator, a shared host server, it no longer works.  Well the home page works but the links to the sub-pages don't.

For example, the following route works fine on my local version:

```
Route::get('/appointments', 'AppointmentController@index');
```

But if I use that route on the remote server, it takes it to tekknow.net/appointments instead of tekknow.net/medaverter/appointments.

So I followed instructions from here:
https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/routing#route-group-sub-domain-routing
and added a prefix like this:

```
Route::prefix('MedAverter')->group(function() {
  Route::get('/appointments', 'AppointmentController@index');
});
```

But that doesn't work either.  It also goes to /tekknow.net/appointments

I also tried changing the route to this:

```
Route::get('/MedAverter/appointments', 'AppointmentController@index');
```

But that also went to tekknow.net/appointments

Anybody know what I'm doing wrong?

**EDIT**: I went onto my HostGator cPanel and looked at all my subdomains and saw that my subdomain root was medaverter.tekknow.net which is linked to Document root of medaverter.tekknow.net/MedAverter which gets redirected to http://www.tekknow.net/MedAverter.  So I renamed my folder from medaverter to MedAverter to match the subdomain redirection.

Here is a screenshot showing what I see in cPanel for columns Subdomains.Root Domain, Document Root, and Redirection
[image]

Comment: I'm a bit confused. You mentioned "subdomain" but from the code it seems you are trying to deploy Laravel in subpath "medaverter". So is it a subdomain (eg. `medaverter.tekknow.net`) or subpath (eg. `tekknow.net/medaverter`)? I think you should also describe your deployment directory structure to help others analyze your problem

Comment: do u want to go to `medaverter.tekknow.net/appointments`?

Comment: In my HostGator account, medaverter.tekknow.net is defined to goto www.tekknow.net/medaverter.  I don't know if you call that a subdomain or a subpath.

Comment: Which domain is reading your applications public folder?

Comment: yes, if I enter medaverter.tekknow.net it takes me to tekknow.net/medaverter.  I have many subdomains.  each one has its own public folder.

Comment: Here is the contents of my /www/medaverter folder: 
./, .gitattributes, README.md, artisan, css/, index.php, phpunit.xml, server.php, webpack.mix.js, .gitignore, Vagrantfile, bootstrap/, database/, js/, public/, storage/,
.editorconfig, .htaccess, after.sh, composer.json, error_log, mix-manifest.json,  resources/,  tests/
.env           .styleci.yml    aliases      composer.lock  favicon.ico  package-lock.json  robots.txt   uploads/
.git/          .vagrant/       app/         config/        img/         package.json       routes/      vendor/

Comment: plz try `php artisan route:list | grep appointments`

Comment: sl1k7f3j@tekknow.net [~/www/MedAverter]# php artisan route:list | grep appointments
|        | GET|HEAD  | MedAverter/appointments                   |                      | App\Http\Controllers\AppointmentController@index        | web          |

Comment: if you input `tekknow.net/MedAverter/appointments` in browser, is it working?

Comment: Hmm.  It was working before I just did the rename from medaverter to MedAverter.  Now I get a 404 page not found error.  If you go to tekknow.net/MedAverter you will see the home page.  But then if you hover over the Appointments link, you will see in the status it is going to go to www.tekknow.net/appointments instead of www.tekknow.net/MedAverter/appointments.

Comment: what about the nginx config root, did u link to the `MedAverter/public/`?

Comment: sorry, I'm not familiar with that term: nginx config root.  If this helps, there is a www@ in my root directory, which as I understand, is a symlink that is the same as public_html.

Answer (score 1):

When you try `php artisan route:list | grep appointments`,

it prints:

```sh
[~/www/MedAverter]# php artisan route:list | grep appointments 

| | GET|HEAD | MedAverter/appointments | | App\Http\Controllers\AppointmentController@index | web |
```

That means your route `MedAverter/appointments` is working for laravel.

`Error 404` means route cannot be found.

So I think that's something wrong with your nginx configuration.

When I try http://tekknow.net/MedAverter/MedAverter/appointments. 
It has really found the route  with error 500.
[image: medaverter-500]

So, I think you have defined this code in your nginx configuration:

```
  location = / {
    rewrite ^ https://tekknow.net/MedAverter;
  }
```

### Solution 1:

Change back to `rewrite ^ https://tekknow.net/;` in nginx configuration.

(I'm not familiar with hostGatar cPanel, but I think you can change `medaverter.tekknow.net/MedAverter` **redirected** to http://www.tekknow.net/`)

And in your laravel project, you need to keep `prefix MedAverter` to `appointments`.

### Solution 2:

Keep the `rewrite` code. It means you don't need to change the cPanel redirect.

And remove `prefix MedAverter` in laravel routes. HostGatar(Nginx) will automatically redirect with this prefix `MedAverter` for `appointments`.

Comment: I removed group prefix from route.  Now when I do http://tekknow.net/MedAverter/MedAverter/appointments, it says: 404 | Not Found.  If I do  http://tekknow.net/MedAverter/appointments, it also says: 404 | Not Found.  I googled nginx and it says it is some kind of program.  As far as I know I am not using it, unless it is some default that HostGator uses.

Comment: @user3217883 I'm not familiar with hostGatar cPanel, but I think you can change medaverter.tekknow.net/MedAverter redirected to http://www.tekknow.net/ without MedAverter, But the laravel routes keep the prefix `MedAverter`. and then try tekknow.net/MedAverter/appointments,

Comment: I was able to disable the redirection in hostgator for the subdomain.  Then I put the route back into a group like this: Route::group(['prefix' => 'MedAverter'], function() {
  Route::get('MedAverter/appointments', 'AppointmentController@index');
});
But same result!

Comment: @user3217883 can u plz change redirect to `http://www.tekknow.net/` and let me visit the site?

Comment: I also tried the route like this: Route::group(['prefix' => 'MedAverter'], function() {
  Route::get('/appointments', 'AppointmentController@index');
});
But same result.  I just changed the subdomain redirection to http://www.tekknow.net.

Comment: @user3217883 I think after you change the cpanel, it still not works, it still redirect to http://www.tekknow.net/MedAverter/, may be you need to restart or do some thing to make your changed work.

Comment: I'll call HostGator to see what I need to do.  Probably it just needs some more time to kick in.  I called HostGator and they said it takes 4-8 hours to propagate around to all the servers in the world.

Answer (score 0):

### Clear all caches

The problem you're getting can be due to cache. So, make sure that's not the problem by running

```
php artisan route:clear && php artisan view:clear && php artisan config:clear && php artisan cache:clear && php artisan clear-compiled
```

### Base URL

If you want to change the base URL of your Laravel app, that's something already [asked](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35304448/5675325).

### Multiple Path Prefixes

In this case you have a more than one route with the same prefix in their path. If that's the case, you can use route groups to simplify the structure.

```
Route::prefix('medaverter')->group(function () {
    Route::get('/', function () {
        // Path /medaverter
    });
    Route::get('appointments', function () {
        // Path /medaverter/appointments
    });
});
```

This would go to, respectively, `tekknow.net/medaverter` and `tekknow.net/medaverter/appointments`. You could also create another prefix, like `testing`, configure in the same way and go to `tekknow.net/testing` or  `tekknow.net/testing/whatever`.

### Namespace prefixes

When you’re grouping routes by route prefix, it’s likely their controllers have a similar PHP namespace. In the medaverter example, all of the medaverter routes’ controllers might be under a Medaverter namespace.

```
Route::namespace('Medaverter')->group(function () {
    // App\Http\Controllers\Medaverter\AppointmentController
    Route::get('medaverter/appointments', 'AppointmentController@index');
});
```

Comment: I cleared cache per your instructions.  Same result.  I implemented code in Multiple Path Prefixes section per your instructions.  Same result.  Controllers do not contain a medaverter name space since local version does not use it.

Comment: Did you try also with Namespace prefixes?

Comment: Just tried it like this: Route::namespace('MedAverter')->group(function() {
  Route::get('MedAverter/appointments', 'AppointmentController@index');
});
but same result

Answer (score 0):

u can use route groups for that here is a sample try this:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'medaverter'], function () {
        Route::get('/appointments', [AppointmentController::class, 'index'])->name('index');
     
});
```

or

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'medaverter'], function () {
    Route::get('/appointments', 'AppointmentController@index');
 
});
```

Comment: I added a ] just before the first comma, then it once again took me to tekknow.net/appointments instead of tekknow.net/medaverter/appointments